# Distribution of the minimum of two uniform random variates

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

> Suppose $X,Y\sim U(0,1)$ are iid random variables and $Z=\min(X,Y)$. Find the pdf and expected value of $Z$.

I've worked this out before when $Z=\max(X,Y)$, but I can't even start here with the maximum replaced with the minimum. Any help?

Comment: It might help to note that $\min\{x,y\}+\max\{x,y\} = x+y$.

Answer (score 6):

For $\max\{X,Y\}$ the key is that $\mathbb{P}(\max\{X,Y\}\leq z)=\mathbb{P}(X\leq z,Y\leq z)$.

So for the minimum, what can you say about $\mathbb{P}(\min\{X,Y\}>z)$?

Comment: is it P(min{X,Y} > z) = P(X>z,Y>z)? or is greater than or equal to?

Comment: That's right, $\mathbb{P}(\min\{X,Y\}>z)=\mathbb{P}(X>z,Y>z)$.

Comment: Okay, so for the problem when it is max{X,Y}, how i proceed is: Since X and Y are independent,
F(c) = P(Z ≤ c) = P(X ≤ c and Y ≤ c) = P(X ≤ c) P(Y ≤ c) = c^2

Comment: Right, and the same approach works here: $\mathbb{P}(X>z,Y>z)=(1-z)^2$.

Comment: But what is the P(x>z) equal to? 1-c? so it would equal (1-c)^2?

Comment: Yes, so the CDF is $F(z)=1-(1-z)^2$ for $0\leq z\leq 1$.

Comment: Wait why is there an additional subtraction from 1 outside the parentheses?

Comment: Because $\mathbb{P}(\min\{X,Y\}\leq z)=1-\mathbb{P}(\min\{X,Y\}>z)$.

Comment: I guess I am missing a really big conceptual point. why do I want to find P(min{X,Y}≤z)? How does that get me closer to the pdf?

Comment: $F(z)=\mathbb{P}(\min\{X,Y\}\leq z)$ is the CDF, and you differentiate it to get the pdf.

Comment: So I got 2-2z and then I integrated z(2-2z) from 0 to 1 to get the expected value of 1/3?

Comment: That's correct.